# Ensure unwanted names removed in class definition

Tags: python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.x

How can I ensure incidental names don't end up in the class definition, with code that works on both Python 2 and Python 3?

With the following class definition, the incidental names `'foo'` and `'bar'`, only needed for the list comprehension, remain in the `Parrot` namespace:

```python
__metaclass__ = type

class Parrot:
    """ A parrot with beautiful plumage. """

    plumage = [
            (foo, bar) for (foo, bar) in feathers.items()
            if bar == "beautiful"]

assert hasattr(Parrot, 'plumage')  # ← okay, has the wanted name
assert not hasattr(Parrot, 'foo')  # ← FAILS, has an unwanted name
assert not hasattr(Parrot, 'bar')  # ← FAILS, has an unwanted name
```

So I can remove those names after using them:

```python
__metaclass__ = type

class Parrot:
    """ A parrot with beautiful plumage. """

    plumage = [
            (foo, bar) for (foo, bar) in feathers.items()
            if bar == "beautiful"]
    del foo, bar

assert hasattr(Parrot, 'plumage')  # ← okay, has the wanted name
assert not hasattr(Parrot, 'foo')  # ← okay, no unwanted name
assert not hasattr(Parrot, 'bar')  # ← okay, no unwanted name
```

But that fails on Python 3, since the names *don't* persist from the list comprehension:

```python
__metaclass__ = type

class Parrot:
    """ A parrot with beautiful plumage. """

    plumage = [
            (foo, bar) for (foo, bar) in feathers.items()
            if bar == "beautiful"]
    del foo, bar  # ← FAILS, “NameError: name 'foo' is not defined”
```

How can I write the class definition with the list comprehension and *not* keep the incidental names — in code that will run correctly on both Python 2 and Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of a list comprehension, it will leak the names in Python 2 and won't leak the names in Python 3. This is [documented as deprecated behaviour](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id20).

A [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), on the other hand, will not leak names in either Python 2 or Python 3. So the list can be constructed from a generator:

```python
__metaclass__ = type

class Parrot:
    """ A parrot with beautiful plumage. """

    plumage = list(
            (foo, bar) for (foo, bar) in feathers.items()
            if bar == "beautiful")

assert hasattr(Parrot, 'plumage')  # ← okay, has the wanted name
assert not hasattr(Parrot, 'foo')  # ← okay, no unwanted name
assert not hasattr(Parrot, 'bar')  # ← okay, no unwanted name
```

This will result in no “leaked” names in the class namespace, in Python 2 nor Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch `NameError` within the class scope to make this work:

```
class Parrot:
    """ A parrot with beautiful plumage. """
    plumage = [
            (foo, bar) for (foo, bar) in feathers.items()
            if bar == "beautiful"]
    try:
        del foo, bar
    except NameError:
        pass
```

You may need to adjust this a little bit to ensure you try / catch around each individual variable name.

Unrelated, but you can do quite surprising things this way:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     import collections
...
>>> A().collections.defaultdict(list)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
```

Comment: That's a good solution in general, +1. However, the specific problem has a better answer.

Comment: @bignose: thanks. I agree that you solution is better.